# Catch exception in Protractor 2.0, make onError function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I got this error in protractor:

> Uncaught exception: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize
>   with the page after 60 seconds. Please see
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

And after that nothing else happends and that is a problem to me because in my conf file, on `onComplete` I have a function that writes tests results in JSON files, but if that error occurs system never get to that function.
Another problem is that browser window is not closed.

I would like to catch that exception, or simulate `onError` function in conf file. I searched in [Protractor API](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md) but there is nothing about `onComplete` or `onPrepare` so also nothing about `onError`. Is that part of Jasmine?

Notice that `Uncaught exception` is not a normal error as could be when one `expect()` fails or a normal `timeout` error.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-catch-errors-such-as-elementnotfound

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a single top level place where all exceptions can be caught, because of the async nature of the promises.

Instead, I would suggest actually passing an exception-handling function to any promise that is fulfilled.

Thus, in any test case, whenever I use a `then` (or a chain of `then`s) on a promise, I make sure I also provide a function as *second* argument to handle any exception that might occur.

For example:

```
function o_O(reason) {
  expect(reason.name).toBe("");
  expect(reason.message).toBe("");
  expect(reason.stack).toBe("");
}

it(' ....', function() {
  loginElt.click().then(function () {
    ...
  }, o_O);
});
```

This will just make the test case fail upon an unexpected exception, and report the relevant non-empty information from the exception.

Answer (score 0):

do it in node:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
  console.error('unhandled', error.stack || error);
});
```